# Custom styling for cluster images in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, html5

new with OpenLayers 3.

While it is possible to generate simple polygons and circles (like in the [cluster](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/cluster.html) example) I wish to generate a more complex Cluster style that varies depending on the features contained in the cluster.

For instance, I would like to generate a dynamic pie chart based on values. It is possible to render this client-side using HTML5 canvas function ([arc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc)) and friends, but I cannot find a way to generate such a drawing using generic canvas primitives within OL3's styles.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? If impossible, I'll "enhance" OL3 with the missing functionality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert a canvas to a HTML Image, you can use the `ol.style.Icon` to display your canvas.

Given that `canvas` is a ready canvas to be used, you must use a style like this:

```
 var image = new Image();
 image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

 style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
       img: image,
       imgSize: [canvas.width,canvas.height],
      })
 });
```

and then style it using something like:

```
var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: clusterSource,
          style: style
        });
```